# ViewPager set current page programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I wrote a custom `ViewPager` to disable `Swipe Scroll`, but I want to swipe programmatically. I have three `Tab` in my view pager, but when I call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1)` on the first `Fragment`, it moves to the third `Fragment` instead of the second `Fragment`. And if I call same function in the second `Fragment`, it goes to the third. If I call (viewPager.getCurrentItem()-1)` in the third fragment, it works fine by moving back. Any help would be appreciated. My code is below:

**NonSwipeAbleViewPager**

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

private boolean swipeable;

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyViewPager);
    try {
        swipeable = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.MyViewPager_swipeable, true);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return swipeable ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event) : false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return swipeable ? super.onTouchEvent(event) : false;
}
}
```

**Declaration in XML**

```
<co.example.customview.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:swipeable="false" />
```

**Calling it**

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuNext:
            NonSwipeableViewPager pages = (NonSwipeableViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
            pages.setCurrentItem(pages.getCurrentItem()+1, true);
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that when you press on the menuNext button the first button you are on the fragment at index 0 ?

Comment: I think I remember some similar oddities when working with it like this at some point.  I just can't recall what the resolution was.

Comment: Have you tried separating the statements?

int currentItem = pages.getCurrentItem();
currentItem++;
pages.setCurrentItem(currentItem);

Comment: I am. I tried to have it Logged by `Log.e("PAGES:", String.valueOf(pager.getCurrentItem()));` The funny thing is that, if I am on the second tab and move to the third tab, it doesnt log. But, if I'm on the first and click on the third Tab, it logs the page as `2`

Comment: @JohnP. Same thing. Moves to the third page

Comment: If you don't want the `ViewPager` to be swipe-able, so why don't you consider using `ViewSwitcher` or `ViewFlipper`?

Comment: Well, I was able to debug deeper now. And I noticed something, calling the same `R.id.menuNext` in different fragment makes it move it to the third by default. Fixed it

Comment: @abforce can you attach `ViewFlipper` or `ViewSwitcher` to a Tab?

Comment: @ItuokeAjanlekoko What do you mean by *Tab*? `ViewFlipper` and `ViewSwitcher` is used to switch between a couple of views attached to it.

Comment: @abforce same as ViewPager and you can attach it to a Tab indicating to the user which page they're in

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In your PagerActivity use

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            int pagei = position + 1;
            pages=pagei + "";

            Toast.makeText(PagerActivity.this, getString(R.string.changeinfopage) + " " + pages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

and

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_previous:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                return true;

            case R.id.action_next:

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

   }
```

Comment: any way to animate it?

Answer (score 90):

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(idx);
```

where idx is 0 based integer.

Comment: The Question is *ViewPager set current page programatically* , thus this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 37):

try this :

```
  viewPager.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
}, 10);
```

sometimes, setCurrentItem on viewpager doesn't work. As pager's content was controlled by a spinner. both the spinners and the pagers state were restored onResume, and because of this the spinners onItemSelected listener was called during the next event propagation cycle.

By using handler we can make this work because it set the pagers current position after the onItemSelected event fired.

Comment: Wasted an hour trying to find out why setCurrentItem was displaying both fragments on the same page. This fixed it!

Comment: for my self without this added delay "setCurrentItem" did not work