# how do I set the current item programatically in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

So in the the old `ViewPager`, you could set the initial position of the `ViewPager` using

`viewPager.setCurrentItem(x)`

How do you do that in `ViewPager2`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewPager set current page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968512/viewpager-set-current-page-programmatically)

Comment: @YabazeCool no, that one is for the old ViewPager. My question has been handled answered below, but thanks anyways!

Comment: [Migration Guide from ViewPager to ViewPager2][1]
[Reference Demo][2]         
here also they are using `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);`.


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration
  [2]: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2#viewpager

Comment: Yes, I got that. some weird bug in android studio was showing the method in red so i thought the method was changed. but restarting the thing seemed to work

Answer (score 5):

[`setCurrentItem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int)) is also an API on ViewPager2, so you should use that.

Answer (score 3):

It works the same way in ViewPager2: [`setCurrentItem(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int)).

But do note the caveat mentioned in the docs:

> Silently ignored if the adapter is not set or empty.

You may be calling it before setting the adapter, or before adding data to the adapter.  Ensure that the adapter is set and populated with data *before* calling `setCurrentItem`.