# ViewPager2: Can't select particular fragment programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2, fragmentstateadapter

I'm trying to select particular fragment say, 2nd or 3rd fragment in ViewPager2 programmatically. It's not working properly. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Although It's working for `TabLayout` every time.

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried using **ViewPager2.post** like `paymentViewpager.post { paymentViewpager.currentItem = 1 }`.
2. Tried adding `paymentViewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)` in `TabLayoutMediator` callback.
3. I have double checked that I'm calling `paymentViewpager.setCurrentItem` after adapter is being set.

Code is like below.

In onCreate of an Activity

```
if (!isGuestUser) {
        getPaymentMethod()
        viewModel.getMyProfile()
    } else {
        val adapter = SecureCheckoutPaymentSelectionAdapter(
                activity = this,
                callback = this,
                gPayCallback = this,
                paypalCallBack = this,
                cardPaymentList = arrayListOf(),
                gPayPaymentDetail = arrayListOf(),
                payPalPaymentDetail = arrayListOf(),
                isPaymentMethodPresent = false,
                itemsCount = THREE,
                userType = userType,
                isGuestUser
        )
        binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentViewpager.adapter = adapter

        initTabLayout()
    }

private fun initTabLayout() {
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentTab, binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentViewpager) { tab, position ->
        val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<LayoutTabImageBinding>(LayoutInflater.from(this), R.layout.layout_tab_image, tab.view, true)

        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                view.icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.card_payment))
            }
            1 -> {
                view.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.google_pay_primary_logo)
            }
            else -> {
                view.icon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.paypal_card))
            }
        }
        tab.customView = view.root
        binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentViewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
    }.attach()
}
```

When API response comes after a while, I need to select 2nd Fragment of ViewPager2. Below code executes in that function.

```
val adapter = SecureCheckoutPaymentSelectionAdapter(
                                activity = this,
                                callback = this,
                                gPayCallback = this,
                                paypalCallBack = this,
                                cardPaymentList = if (userType == PERSONAL_USER_TYPE) paymentSavedResponse.personalCards as ArrayList<PaymentMethod>
                                else paymentSavedResponse.businessCards as ArrayList<PaymentMethod>,
                                gPayPaymentDetail = paymentSavedResponse.googlePay as ArrayList<GooglePay>,
                                payPalPaymentDetail = paymentSavedResponse.paypalAccount,
                                isPaymentMethodPresent = paymentSavedResponse.paymentMethodPresent,
                                itemsCount = THREE,
                                userType = userType,
                                isGuestUser
                        )
                        binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentViewpager.adapter = adapter

                        initTabLayout()
                        setViewPagerClick()

                        if (paymentSavedResponse.latestPaymentDetails?.paymentMethodPresent == true) {
                            Log.e("mk", "in paymentMethodPresent == true...")
                            when {
                                paymentSavedResponse.latestPaymentDetails.paymentMethod.size > ZERO -> {
                                    Log.e("mk", "in card...")
                                    binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.apply {
                                        paymentViewpager.currentItem = ZERO
                                        //paymentTab.selectTab(paymentTab.getTabAt(ZERO))
                                    }
                                }
                                paymentSavedResponse.latestPaymentDetails.googlePay.size > ZERO -> {
                                    Log.e("mk", "in GPay...")
                                    binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.apply {
                                        paymentViewpager.currentItem = ONE
                                        //paymentTab.selectTab(paymentTab.getTabAt(ONE))
                                    }
                                }
                                else -> {
                                    Log.e("mk", "in Else...")
                                    binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.apply {
                                        paymentViewpager.currentItem = TWO
                                        //paymentTab.selectTab(paymentTab.getTabAt(TWO))
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

I have came across same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63369694/5716010) which is don't have accepted answer yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this with `ViewPager2`, for me the reason was enabling the smoothScroll (second parameter in [setCurrentItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean))) as enabling it makes the `ViewPager` goes to a wrong page

So the fix was to disable it:

```
binding.includeSecureCheckoutPaymentDetails.paymentViewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, false)
```

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you require any further information from my side.

Comment: Can you try `paymentViewpager.postDelayed()` with some delay

Comment: I had tried, although let me try one more time. @Zain

Comment: I have tried with 500 and 1000 milliseconds, it rarely doesn't work. Most of the times It is working. Is this a proper solution? @Zain

Comment: No it should be something like 100msec or 200ms as max, greater than that shouldn't be proper solution, we just need to make sure that's not pending on any other UI thing in the main thread loop... there must be something else causing this

Comment: Okay. I will check with max 200ms. Thanks for the help. @Zain

Comment: @MaulikDodia Can you also log down the `tab.position` and see if it's already correct before setting it to the `viewPager`

Comment: `tab.position` is everytime `-1` and I have noticed that It is with 500ms of delay, It is working like 80% of the times. Not all the time. @Zain

Comment: Cool now we knew why the viewpager went to wrong fragment... Can you use *position* instead of *tab.position*

Comment: I will try and let you know. @Zain